# Is there a way to run terraform apply for a specific tfstate file?

Tags: terraform, tfstate

Is there a way to run terraform apply for a specific tfstate file?
By default it takes terraform.tfstate but I need to rename it as I am managing multiple state files in azure.

Folder structure:[image]

Comment: If not already, you could maybe try using terraform workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `terraform apply` help there is the `-state` flag:

> -state=path            Path to read and save state (unless state-out
> is specified). Defaults to "terraform.tfstate".

Executing:

- `terraform plan -state=yourfilename`, and later
- `terraform apply -state=yourfilename`;

will let you specify the state filename.

Please note, the file extension does not need to be `.tfstate` and you can use whatever file name.

Comment: Tried to run the command but its giving me the following error.
I have the tfstate and the main.tf file in the same directory,do I still need to change it via -chdir ?
Also I have not mentioned state-out anywhere.


PS C:\Users\Desktop\Terraform> terraform plan -state=terraform.tfstate

------------------------------------------------------------------
╷
│ Error: Too many command line arguments
│
│ To specify a working directory for the plan, use the global -chdir flag.
╵

For more help on using this command, run:
  terraform plan -help
PS C:\Users\Desktop\Terraform>

Comment: @Ghostrider did you make sure there are no spaces when specifying the option. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587927/too-many-command-line-arguments-terraform-plan

Comment: Nops no space  terraform plan -state=terraform.tfstate

Comment: @Ghostrider could you edit the question with the folder structure or something else helpful to see what could be the problem?

Comment: Yup updated the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can name your state file as you please if you are using Azure storage to manage your remote state:

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "<resource_group>"
    storage_account_name = "<storage_group>"
    container_name       = "<container_name>"
    key                  = "hello_world.tfstate" <-- tf state filename
  }
}
```

Also, check on [Terraform workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces) as that be helpful to you as well.

Locally run init and plan to make sure there are no changes expected before running apply.

Push change through CI/CD pipeline to merge into main with no changes for apply to worry about.

Once you are done you can delete the older copy of the state file from storage.

Comment: Hi Tom
1) I went through workspaces, but the thing is I am in a process of creating tfstate files for multiple resources and placing them in the same folder. Now when I make some change in the tfvars I need to call that specific tfstate file to check the current config.Workspaces will create folder for each resource and that's not exactly what I am looking after.
2) As of now the storage options for me are my machine in sync with git.