# Azure appservice using terraform gives error ""/providers/Microsoft.Web/sourceControls/GitHub" already exists"

Tags: azure, github, compiler-errors, terraform, azure-web-app-service

Azure appservice creation with terraform is giving error below:

> A resource with the ID "/providers/Microsoft.Web/sourceControls/GitHub" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State.

I ran the below command-

```
terraform import azurerm_source_control_token.dobble_token /providers/Microsoft.Web/sourcecontrols/GitHub
```

But it gives the error below:-

> ID must be exactly "/providers/Microsoft.Web/sourceControls/GitHub".

I gave id in the format below:-

`azurerm_source_control_token.dobble_token` as `"/providers/Microsoft.Web/sourceControls/GitHub"`. I Still  face the same error.

Could someone help me resolve this?

Comment: Yes, make sure the resource id is correct, You can try using this command with correct resource id as terraform is case sensitive- terraform import azurerm_source_control_token.dobble_token /providers/Microsoft.Web/sourceControls/GitHub

Comment: This worked. @SiddheshDesai Do u know how to give this import command in azure devops pipeline. When I gave this command in additional commands column it gave error "Too many arguments. Need one positional argument".

Comment: In devops you can use custom command like here- https://i.imgur.com/J9CYtht.png

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I gave import command. Still it gives error "Too many arguments". If itss custom how to give terraform init further. With custom also its giving same error

Comment: "Too many arguments. Need one positional argument" in devops pipeline. This looks like a new error code, Can you create new question for this error with details for me to test in my environment?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/preg0.png
@SiddheshDesai
If I gave terraform import azurerm_source_control_token.dobble_token /providers/Microsoft.Web/sourceControls/GitHub in additional commands column, its giving eror "Too many arguments. Need one positional argument".

Comment: I'll try and get back to you

Comment: I am awaiting the answer. After that will accept the solution

Comment: @SiddheshDesai Hi you got the answer? Sorry to ask. Just to know whether you got.

Comment: Any one can u help

Comment: @SiddheshDesai sorry. Could you help

Comment: @user14805556 Can  you check this SO thread answer on the same error, code -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587927/too-many-command-line-arguments-terraform-plan looks like the terraform import command you are using is not in correct format

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below **`terraform code`** **to create app Service with source control** from this [**document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/provision-resource-terraform).

**My main.tf code referred from the document above but modified to print source_control resource id:-**

```
# Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Generate a random integer to create a globally unique name
resource "random_integer" "ri" {
  min = 10000
  max = 99999
}

# Create the resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "myResourceGroup-${random_integer.ri.result}"
  location = "eastus"
}

# Create the Linux App Service Plan
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                = "webapp-asp-${random_integer.ri.result}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}


resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "webapp" {
  name                  = "webapp-${random_integer.ri.result}"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  service_plan_id       = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
  https_only            = true
  site_config { 
    minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
  }
}

#  Deploy code from a public GitHub repo
resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "sourcecontrol" {
  app_id             = azurerm_linux_web_app.webapp.id
  repo_url           = "https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world"
  branch             = "master"
  use_manual_integration = true
  use_mercurial      = false
}

# Output the resource ID of azurerm_app_service_source_control
output "source_control_resource_id" {
  value = azurerm_app_service_source_control.sourcecontrol.id
}
```

***Print the resource id of source control by adding the code snippet below in main.tf code:-***

```
# Output the resource ID of azurerm_app_service_source_control
output "source_control_resource_id" {
  value = azurerm_app_service_source_control.sourcecontrol.id
}
```

[image]

And then import the source control latest state with the command below by using the resource id printed in the terminal with the code above.

```
terraform import azurerm_app_service_source_control.sourcecontrol /subscriptions/xxxxx44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup-56454/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/webapp-56454
```

[image]

*As my resource is already managed by terraform it gave me the warning above.*